# SQL sort by max from children

Tags: sql, join

I have this kind of shema in my database :

```
    create table a (
      id serial
    );

    create table b (
      id serial,
      aId integer REFERENCES a(id)
    );

    create table c (
      id serial,
      bId integer REFERENCES b(id),
      date datetime
    );
```

I would like to get all A sorted by the date in C (DESC) following this relation : A -> B -> C.

I came up with this solution :

```
    SELECT
      a.*
    FROM
      a
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          b.aId,
          max(sub1.max) AS max
        FROM
          b
          JOIN (
            SELECT
              c.bId AS id,
              max(c.date) AS max
            FROM
              c
            GROUP BY
              c.bId
          ) AS sub1 ON sub1.id = b.id
      ) AS sub2 ON sub2.aId = a.id
    GROUP BY
      a.id
    ORDER BY
      sub2.max desc
```

Is this the most suitable way to handle this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `order by`:

```
select a.*
from a
order by (select max(c.date)
          from b join
               c
               on c.bid = b.id
          where b.aid = a.id
         ) desc;
```

Alternatively, if you only want `aid` and insist that there be matches, you can just use aggregation:

```
select b.aid
from b join
     c
     on c.bid = b.id
group by b.aid
order by max(c.date) desc;
```

Comment: Perfect, it seems better than my naive query. Thanks a lot ! 